# How to add Order by in UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ISNULL(TradeName,RegisteredName) ='' THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(ISNULL(TradeName,RegisteredName),' (',LocType,')') END [Description] ,'' [Param1]
FROM a.Table1
ORDER BY [Description] ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT '' [Code],'' [Description],'' [Param1]
ORDER BY [Description] ASC
```

I'm having this problem, when I tried `ASC` my Description I'm getting this error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Can anyone help me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: remove the first `ORDER BY`. There can be only one `ORDER BY` clause in the query

Comment: Hi Squirrel I've also tried that and I have this error

`Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`

Answer (score 4):

Two issues here.

1. union only gets a single order by and it must come at the end to handle the entire data set
2. when unioning two queries, they must have the same number of columns in each select statement. I've added a `'' code,` to the first select below, however you will need to fill that in with something that makes.more sense or perhaps a null instead.

```sql
    SELECT 
        '' [code],
        CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(TradeName,RegisteredName) ='' THEN '' 
            ELSE CONCAT(ISNULL(TradeName,RegisteredName),' (',LocType,')') 
        END [Description],
        '' [Param1]
    FROM a.Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        '' [Code],
        '' [Description],
        '' [Param1]
ORDER BY [Description] ASC
```